# break-word for wrapping the text

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

- i am new to css wrap property.
- I tried to wrap the etx by giving bot the properties
  // wordWrap: "break-word"
  overflowWrap: "break-word"
- but still its overlapping in the next div.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- I need to maintain same width and height in all divs.
- is there any way I can fix it.
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-omvw3

```or-tag-here
 right_container: {
    float: "right",
    border: "1px solid #000",
    // background: '#f60',
    padding: 10
  },
  right_box: {
    border: "1px solid #000",
    // padding: 5,
    // background: '#ff0',
    marginTop: 8,
    marginRight: 8,
    float: "left",
    //  width: 150,
    height: 55
  },

  right_box_innerLabel: {
    border: "1px solid #000",
    // padding: 5,
    // background: '#ff0',
    marginTop: 8,
    marginRight: 8,
    float: "left",
    //  width: 400,
    height: 24,
    // wordWrap: "break-word"
    overflowWrap: "break-word"
  },

  status_box: {
    border: "1px solid #000",
    // padding: 5,
    //   background: '#ff0',
    margin: 8,
    float: "left"
    //  width: 200,
    // height: 150,
  },
  clr: { clear: "both" }



            <div className={classes.right_box}>
              0<div className={classes.sportsCardHeaderItemHeading}>Sports</div>
              <div className={classes.sportsCardHeaderItemHeadingValue}>
                testing the be Bhere I am here I am here I am here I am here I
                am testing the be Bhere I am here I am here I am here I am here
                I am
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className={classes.right_box}>
              1<div className={classes.sportsCardHeaderItemHeading}>Sports</div>
              <div className={classes.sportsCardHeaderItemHeadingValue}>
                gfbkl;gfkl;gf kl;klkl;kl; k;lkl;kl;kl;kl; kl;kl;kl;kl;bgf
                kkl;;klkl;
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the desired result it, but if you are trying to hide any overflowing text, set `overflow: hidden;` in your css for the div

Comment: Have you looked into css Grid? If not, please look at this [CSS Grid Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: @Ted thanks it worked

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `overflow-wrap` would be sufficient if the height of your boxes was dynamic.

But if the height is fixed, you can use:

- `overflow: hidden;`

Or, to specifically target the vertical axis:

- `overflow-y: hidden;`

This article includes a useful demonstration of `word-wrap` and `overflow-wrap`: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-wrap/